# iOS application is unresponsive after performing [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview]

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm building a very simple iOS iPad app that consists of a view and 4 buttons.
So basically you have in the Storyboard:

```
->ViewController
  ->View (this is added just for alignment and position sake, nothing else)
    ->View
      ->Button1
      ->Button2
      ->Button3
      ->Button4
```

When you press a button a movie will play in fullscreen mode, the same for all 4 buttons.
Once the movie is done, either because it finished or the user pressed "**done**",

`[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview]` is used to remove the movie, and everything returns to the initial state of the app, with the 4 buttons.

this is the code that plays the movie when a button is pressed

```
- (void) playMovie:(NSString *)fileName
            ofType:(NSString *)fileType
{

    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:fileType];

    NSURL *fileUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer play];

}
```

And this is the code I use to stop and remove the movie:

```
    - (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                                  object:player];

    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player stop];
        [player setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

The problem I encounter is this, after `[player.view removeFromSuperview];` is performed, I return to the initial view, **with no background image (it turns black) and no response from any of the buttons**.

if I remove the view that contains the buttons, and add the buttons to the main view, it works as expected.

Sorry if this isn't too clear, I've been through books and lots of websites but don't seem to be able to get my head around this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the MPMoviePlayerController for a MPMoviePlayer**View**Controller and referenced the movie player within it, without using the setFullScreen and everything started working as expected.

So basically adding a view to the superview and the MPMoviePlayerController setFullScreen=YES are no good in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are removing the "player" from the superview, but what you orginally added was a "movieplayer"...try removing that from the superview.

Comment: see that I'm removing the same object, since it's been passed to the method as the notification object, therefore *player = self.moviePlayer.

Comment: I've done some more research and the issue appears to be in the setFullscreen:YES parameter, it's messing everything up...